# What is the best way to drive a user testing?

Tags: users, usability-testing, testing-protocols, users-tests

I'm product designer in software. Next monday I'll drive a user testing session with the product team and I'd like to submit you the way we'll do it. **Could you confirm if it's the best way to do?**

Each user will do the test with 2 "observers". One observer will drive the test and make the user talking and sharing as feedbacks as possible, and the other one will note all his observations.

The user will follow a scenario with tasks.

Session process : 30 min maximum

- **5 min to welcome and brief the user** (we'll thank him for his help, explain that we won't juge him, he can not make mistake because there isn't good or bad answer, we'll give him the context and explain him what he'll have to do...etc)
- **15-20 min to test the app following a scenario** (here I don't know if the best way to do is to give him the scenario on a paper sheet or to drive him by voice)
- **5-10min for feedbacks** (talking about the app, and asking the user about more social and demographic informations). For this step we want to make a questionnaire to be sur that all users will give his last feedbacks in the same order as the others)

Finally we'll thank him again, give some presents (like goodies and vouchers)

Answer (score 3):

You process is fine I confirm. Just a couple of recommendations if you haven't already considered them:

A good practice is to make a **pilot user test** with someone from the company or other friend, to spot mistakes in the instructions phase or the process as a whole. I'm sure you will find a lot of areas for improvement.

Make sure to insruct the users to **talk aloud** while performing the session. This will give you really valuable information.

Also, if there are going to be two observers the user might feel **peer pressure**.  If you can hide one of the observers it will decrease the bias. Not that with one he will not feel peer pressure, but at least you can reduce it. We want as natural settings as we can achieve.

You are ready to go and start testing. Wish you success.

Comment: Thank you for this advices! In fact monday will be the pilot user test with colleagues who don't know yet the interfaces. After that, will try to build our own user process to repeat it every two weeks before the ultimate release.

Comment: And, @kristiyan, do you think I should print the scenario and give it to the user, or one of the observer should just guide him by speaking? Or it doesn't make difference?

Comment: There is not big difference, but it depends on the complexity of the tasks. Before the test you should briefly inform the user on what tasks she has to accomplish and then the researcher should help the user remember what she has to do by speaking.